# How to block access to the home page of the website in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How to block access to the home page of the website in .htaccess?
I can easily block access to specific subpages of the website, e.g. domain.com/blog:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/blog.*$
```

However, I don't know how to block the homepage of the website: domain.com, so that only it is blocked, while the subpages domain.com/blog works.

I tried to add "!" as in PHP (block access to all pages other than /blog) but that doesn't work in .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 404 !^/blog.*$
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just use: `RedirectMatch 404 ^/$`

Comment: No, this block all (home page + subpages)... I want only block home page.

Comment: That's not correct. `RedirectMatch 404 ^/$` only blocks home page but it doesn't block `example.com/subdir/`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm extrapulating the following from this [post](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/redirect-main-domain-but-not-subdomain.221272/):

```
root@host [/home/tristan/public_html]# cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/google\.com" [R=302,L]
```

try to adapt it to your specific domain. It should allow subdomain.domain.com and redirect domain.com to google.com.

---

edit: including comment by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava): `RedirectMatch 404 ^/$` should just block the root, but not the other pages.

Comment: Yes, it works, but how to block all subpages + homepage except /blog ?

Answer (score 0):

You're both right,

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/$
```

It works!
I don't know why, but I checked it before and it didn't work, now it's ok :)

However, I have a second question:
**How to block all subpages + homepage except /blog ?**

Comment: you may post an answer to your own question, but is preferrable to ask separate questions as separate questions.